# Py2exe 64-bit fails to install

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I am wanting to compile all of my python scripts into one exe.  I use the Vizard shell to find errors in my scripts.   When I download the 64-bit install for py2exe (Python 2.7), and try to install it, the exe ignores my Python 2.7 directory, and chooses Vizard as the main directory.  I uninstalled Vizard, rebooted my computer and tried the installation again, but to my surprise, it still had the Vizard directory as my main directory.

When I tried to install a 32-bit version, it located my Python directory just fine.  However, the 32-bit version will not work and gives me ridiculous amounts of errors trying to run it.

Vizard is rather important to me, so I'd love to keep the program. Is there a way to install the 64-bit version outside of an exe?  Thanks for the help.